# Out Of Memory exception while loading mapview in android

Tags: android, android-mapview

In My application i have map view which rotate based on user direction.for this i took map view size very big its crosses the device width and height.But it works perfectly in device but in emulator it showing out of memory exception.I know this is because of low heap memory of emulator.

Is all devices have more heap memory.or any solution is their to solve this?

My Locat output

```
07-05 12:32:49.982: E/AndroidRuntime(907): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
07-05 12:32:49.982: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
07-05 12:32:49.982: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:468)
07-05 12:32:49.982: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at com.google.android.maps.StreetViewRenderer.generateNewTileImage(StreetViewRenderer.java:120)
07-05 12:32:49.982: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at com.google.android.maps.StreetViewRenderer.renderTile(StreetViewRenderer.java:88)
07-05 12:32:49.982: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at com.google.android.maps.AndroidTileOverlayRenderer.renderTile(AndroidTileOverlayRenderer.java:62)
07-05 12:32:49.982: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at com.google.googlenav.map.Map.drawTile(Unknown Source)
07-05 12:32:49.982: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at com.google.googlenav.map.Map.drawMapBackground(Unknown Source)
07-05 12:32:49.982: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at com.google.googlenav.map.Map.drawMap(Unknown Source)
07-05 12:32:49.982: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at com.google.android.maps.MapView.drawMap(MapView.java:1048)
07-05 12:32:49.982: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at com.google.android.maps.MapView.onDraw(MapView.java:486)
07-05 12:32:49.982: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6740)
07-05 12:32:49.982: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1640)
07-05 12:32:49.982: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
07-05 12:32:49.982: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at com.trafficmate.utils.RotateView.dispatchDraw(RotateView.java:48)
07-05 12:32:49.982: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
07-05 12:32:49.982: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
07-05 12:32:49.982: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
07-05 12:32:49.982: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
07-05 12:32:49.982: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
07-05 12:32:49.982: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
07-05 12:32:49.982: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
07-05 12:32:49.982: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
07-05 12:32:49.982: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
07-05 12:32:49.982: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
07-05 12:32:49.982: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
07-05 12:32:49.982: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
07-05 12:32:49.982: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
07-05 12:32:49.982: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
07-05 12:32:49.982: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:1638)
07-05 12:32:49.982: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:1367)
07-05 12:32:49.982: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.View.draw(View.java:6743)
07-05 12:32:49.982: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:352)
07-05 12:32:49.982: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:1842)
07-05 12:32:49.982: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.ViewRoot.draw(ViewRoot.java:1407)
07-05 12:32:49.982: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1163)
07-05 12:32:49.982: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1727)
07-05 12:32:49.982: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-05 12:32:49.982: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-05 12:32:49.982: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-05 12:32:49.982: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-05 12:32:49.982: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-05 12:32:49.982: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-05 12:32:49.982: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-05 12:32:49.982: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I used RotateView with Extenting View Group

onMeasure Method of Rotate View

```
private static final float SQ2 = 3.5f;
  @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        int w = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumWidth(), widthMeasureSpec);
        int h = getDefaultSize(getSuggestedMinimumHeight(), heightMeasureSpec);
       //int w=SonarView.display.getWidth();
       //int h=SonarView.display.getHeight();
        int sizeSpec;
        if (w > h) {
            sizeSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec((int) (w * SQ2), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        } else {
            sizeSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec((int) (h * SQ2), MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
        }
        final int count = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            getChildAt(i).measure(sizeSpec, sizeSpec);
        }
        Log.e("sizeSpec",""+sizeSpec);

        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
```

And My layout is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
<com.trafficmate.utils.RotateView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/rview"
 >
<com.google.android.maps.MapView 
android:id="@+id/mapview"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:apiKey="0947Aqi7xG3QScZEvvOLtLJNtVss6PFjAquxZ2w"
android:clickable="true" 
android:saveEnabled="true"
/>

</com.trafficmate.utils.RotateView>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: full logcat output is required here.

Comment: paste your code and logcat output..

Comment: we need to look at your code to find the mistakes. post your code and the logcat error details

Comment: Seems like this guy: http://rootzwiki.com/topic/9158-how-to-change-vm-heap-size/ have an answer on how to increase heap of emulator. However it would only mask the real problem you are having. I bet code can be improved.

Answer (score 0):

you can increase heap size by adding ***android:largeHeap="true"*** to your Application tag. emulator has same heap size for both regular and large heap, so you have to check it on device.

check it by ActivityManager.getLargeMemoryClass();

Comment: Is it best solution to follow?

Comment: I think android:largeheap="true" is supported only from 3.0